# Selected only one values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have:

```
<select id="number" name="number">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">01</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">02</option>
<option value="3">03</option>
<option value="4" selected="selected">04</option>
<option value="5">05</option>
</select>
```

and next with jQuery i use for example:

```
$('#number').val(1);
```

but this add next value - 1 and now i have:

```
<select id="number" name="number">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1" selected="selected">01</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">02</option>
<option value="3">03</option>
<option value="4" selected="selected">04</option>
<option value="5">05</option>
</select>
```

what i must use with:

```
$('#number').val(1);
```

that all others value can be not selected? So i would like - if i set new val then all others values can be reset. Maybe use each for reset, but how?
I know - this should be multiselect = false, but this is not my code - i must use this this jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a multiple select? Because the HTML you've added indicates that you're not. If you're not working with a multiple select, then your HTML with several `selected="selected"` doesn't make any sense.

If you *are* working with a multiple select, then setting `.val()` *should* clear the other selections. ([Demo](http://jsbin.com/ogosix/edit#javascript,html,live)). If in some weird browser it isn't, you could try manually resetting the select:

```
$('#number option').prop('selected', false).val(1);
```

If clearing the current selection is *not* what you want, then you should consider setting the `selected` property manually, rather than using `.val()`

```
$('#number option[value=1]').prop('selected', true);
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ilixeq/edit#javascript,html,live)